# Settings to send an email from localhost for PHP code in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, email, php, smtp, localhost

I am using PHP 5 and Apache to do programming. My code can correctly send emails on the server, but on my own development machine I cannot send emails. There is clearly nothing wrong with my code, so I guess the problem is with my settings.

I have turned off IIS so that I can assign port 80 to my Apache instance. I did not install PHP, Apache, [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) using [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) or [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), but I installed each component individually.

I have already tried assigning SMTP to localhost in `php.ini` and the port number, etc.

I am running on Windows Vista. I am using a router at home, and I tend to assign a fixed IP address, `192.168.0.9` to my development machine.

I used [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) where I state a specific *from* address and *to* address and once again I insist that the code works on my live server.

It is just not working on my development machine.

Comment: a detail blog here: http://goo.gl/O1zw89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vista does not come with an SMTP server like Windows XP did.

I ran into a similar issue when I switched my development environment to Vista. So, you have to install an SMTP server.

There are many to choose from, but I chose [**Free SMTP Server**](http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html) to handle development needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xmail](http://www.xmailserver.org), it's very easy to configure and get running for the first time,yet you can deploy it for production use too.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer "Free SMTP Server" but , in cases where I want to view the traffic and the messages, then I would choose "[Hamster SMTP Server](http://www.arcorhome.de/newshamster/tgl/misc/hamster_en.html)" , which is also free.