# Settings to send email from localhost for PHP code in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, email, php, smtp, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Settings to send an email from localhost for PHP code in Windows Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/42329)

I am using PHP 5 and Apache to do some programming. My code can correctly send emails on the live server, but on my own development machine, I cannot send emails. There is obviously nothing wrong with my code (since it only fails to send the email on *my* development machine), so I guess the problem is with my settings.

I have turned off IIS so that I can assign port 80 to Apache. I did not install PHP, Apache, or MySQL by using WAMP or XAMPP - I installed each component individually. I have already tried assigning SMTP to localhost in `php.ini` and the port number, etc... Nothing works.

I am running on Windows Vista, and am using a router at home. I assign a fixed IP address (192.168.0.9) to my development machine. I used PHPMailer where I state a specific *from* address and *to* address, and once again, I insist that the code works on my live server - it is just not working on my development machine.

I tried the two solutions given in the last time I asked this question over here:
[Settings to send an email from localhost for PHP code in Windows Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/42329/settings-to-send-email-from-localhost-for-php-code-in-windows-vista)

But it turns out the solution that I accepted had a limit of sending 10 emails a day, and for some reason, it was working intermittently. Also, the other solution required me to jump through too many hoops.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Might want to put this on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'd switch back to Windows XP if I were you. Better yet, use linux.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. Edit the original with more details to get more or better answers.

Comment: detail blog: http://goo.gl/O1zw89

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
<?php
ini_set("SMTP","aspmx.l.google.com");
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: myemail@yahoo.com" . "\r\n";
mail("msome@gmail.com","test subject","test body",$headers);
?>
```